# Gatsby build failing on Netlify. Warning: a promise was created in a handler

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, postcss, contentful, netlify

Build Errors on Netlify. Build exceeds maximum allowed runtime.
Can build locally running yarn build and inside the Netlify docker container, however when on Netlifys build it exceeds maximum allowed runtime.

Am getting some warnings like the below when running in the Netlify docker container
`Warning: a promise was created in a handler at opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:213:17 but was not returned from it`

`Warning: a promise was created in a handler at /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-remark/extend-node-type.js:179:19 but was not returned from it`

Those two warnings are pointing to two Gatsby plugins I have configured. (Config below)

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'My Website',
  },
  proxy: {
    prefix: '/.netlify/functions',
    url: 'http://localhost:9000',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-eslint',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
      options: {
        rule: {
          exclude: /img/,
        },
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images-contentful',
            options: {
              maxWidth: 590,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-netlify', // make sure to keep it last in the array
  ],
};
```

Have tried to debug all weekend but not sure what else to do. I couldn't find anyone else who has had similar issues.